# getting focused jtextfield in exteds jPanel

Tags: java, swing, jdatechooser

i was searching for date chooser solution i'd founed this:

https://pzt.me/9oan (pw bravvve)

in the jFrame:

```
        private JDateChooser getJDateChooser() {  
        if (jChoixDate == null) {  
            jChoixDate = new JDateChooser();  
            jChoixDate  
                    .setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);  
            jChoixDate.setBounds(new Rectangle(198, 90, 88, 21));  
            jChoixDate.estValide(false);  
            //jChoixDate.addActionListener(this);  
            jChoixDate.addFocusListener(this);  
            jChoixDate.getEditor().addFocusListener(this);  

        }  
        return jChoixDate;  
    }
```

i'v done some modifications to know if the datefield is empty or not and some color modifications if its not enabled,well am using this date chooser in some jframe class,and i wan to know if the datefield is in the focus and if it is,i wan i that if i click some button it will be intialized,i'd traid many solution but none hase fonctionned,how can i do that,thanks

Answer (score 2):

consider using good JCalendars/JDatePicker with great reputations, e.g.

1. [JCalendar](http://www.toedter.com/en/jcalendar/)
2. [SwingX](http://java.net/downloads/swingx/releases/)

Comment: ok,thanks but what if i wan to code some exteds jPanel with jTextfields and i wan to use it in another jpanel ,and i wan to do some focus coding how can i permitte that,and how can i get the focus

Comment: Either suggested library works with the [focus subsystem](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html).

Answer (score 0):

Shameless plug:

Use the [JDatePicker](https://github.com/jdatepicker/jdatepicker), you can fork it on github modify it to your heart's content, pull requests will be accepted if you make improvements.